# How to display returned List in c#

Tags: c#

I want to display returned list to other class.
I am returning the list from the method by passing an object of the auto property class, but can't display it...
here is the code.

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
     }

 public List<Person> LoadData() {

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Sara", LastName = "John", Age = 30 });
            people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Tim", LastName = "Joe", Age = 26 });
            people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "James", LastName = "ted", Age = 29 });

            return people;

        }
```

//The other side where I want to display the code is

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var display = new Person();
            var p = new List<Person>();

            p = display.LoadData();

            foreach (var item in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting any Error but it's not displaying data,
It displays

> System.Generice.Collections.MyConsoleApplication.

Comment: You want to override `ToString()`.

Comment: Does your code compile? `LoadData` doesn't belong to `Person` class.

Comment: how do you want it displayed?, in which format ?

Comment: Besides the `ToString` mentioned by SLaks to control the type of output, you are using the collection `p` for the console.writeline. I think you meant to output `item` instead

Comment: it is Compiling @JohnyL

Comment: in string @AhmedGhoniem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Person` is not a `string` and `Console.WriteLine(p);` won't result in what you want.

So there are two ways to go:

Either write it like this:

```
foreach (var item in p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Age));
}
```

Or just override the `ToString()` Method of your Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", FirstName, LastName, Age);
    }
}
```

in this case (second option) your own code will work:

```
foreach (var item in p)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: return is missing in the ToString() method.

Comment: @Unnamed yeah it was missing, hopefully found it ;). Thanks

Comment: Its still not working. getting an error on $ sign which says "Unexpected Character"

Comment: @fatimaAjij it is because you C# version is low, I just changed my code, this should work, please check it.

Comment: @uɐʞɥsɐ hey Thank you so much it worked :) but I didn't understand the logic here, I am storing value via object in list and for generating them I need to convert to string to display?

Comment: @fatimaAjij you are welcome. yes only string values can be displayed. any other type must be converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned the Object.ToString problem.  One other issue in your code is that the for loop is trying to print the collection not the items

> `foreach (var item in p) { Console.WriteLine(p); }`

should be using item not p

> foreach (var item in p) { Console.WriteLine(**item**.ToString()); }

Answer (score 0):

tour Person class does not know how to print string. you need to override ToString()

```
public class Person
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"FirstName = {this.Firstname} \t\t LastName = {this.LastName} \t\t Age = {this.Age}";
    }
}
```

now your foreach will print by using override function

```
foreach (var item in p)
{
     Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName);
```

Comment: OP tries to print whole object rather then property by property

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks @Simonare. Up voting ashkan's answer.